# add column in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using `D3.js` to draw 4 columns inside a row, I have three column with data and I want to add 1 more add the end. My `html` file is like this.

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="feature">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my `Javascript` code is like this.

```
  function calculateNumber(){
    var json_url = "...";
    dataset = []; 
    d3.json(json_url, function(data) {
      dataset.push(intToString(data[0]["num_jobs"]));
      dataset.push(data[0]["cpuhour_tot"]);
      dataset.push(data[0]["cpuhour_tot"]);
        d3.select(".feature .row").selectAll("div")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("div")
          .attr("class", "col-xs-3")
          .text(function(d){ return d});
    });

    new_data = generateStatic();

    d3.select(".feature .row").selectAll("div")
      .data(new_data)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "col-xs-3")
      .text(function(d){ return d});
  }
```

this code add 3 column perfect, now `new_data = generateStatic();` has the new data that I want to add.

dataset and new_dat are different

Now I want to add another div .. but the code no add any new div, simply rewrite the fist.

I include the image where I mark where have to appear the new div

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to `select` via two class names you would need to remove the space between the class name and dot `.`.

```
d3.select(".feature.row").selectAll("div")
```

In your loop you would add the dataset multiple times, I am not sure if this is what you intend to do. Perhaps consider

```
.data(dataset)
```

```js
function calculateNumber() {
  dataset = [
    [1, 2, 1],
    [3, 4, 3],
    [5, 6, 5]
  ];

  d3.select(".feature.row")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "col-xs-3")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d
    });

};

calculateNumber();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="feature">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="item_feature">
          <h2>title </h2>
          <div id="resume_data">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Maximilian Peters I update the question, because I don't explain very well. I create theree div, and I want to add other, but the code rewrite the first div, not create any new, the data that I add in the las div is different that the fisrt one